# Axis label placement between tick lines in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 and i want to position a label between two ticks, so i wonder if there is an easy way to find the distance between two ticks, considering that the axis can scale?

Comment: Anything wrong with (given that x is a scale): `(x(val1) + x(val2)) / 2` ?